# Calculating fibonnacci numbers using fix

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

I am trying to understand how this factorial example works using the function `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`.

[**Example:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)

```
factabs :: (Num a, Eq a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a
factabs fact 0 = 1
factabs fact x = x * fact (x-1)

f :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a
f = fix factabs
```

I do not see why `fix factabs` has this type... `fix` expects a function of type `a -> a`, how can we apply it to a function of type `(a -> a) -> a -> a` (a function that takes two parameters)? I am totally confused...

Basically I was trying to figure out how to convert the function `limit` below to something that uses `fix`. Would appreciate any help.

```
limit f n
    | n == next       = n
    | otherwise       = limit f next
    where
      next = f n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fix expects a function of type `a -> a`, how can we apply it to a function of type `(a -> a) -> a -> a` (a function that takes two parameters)? I am totally confused...

That works because *all Haskell functions take just one parameter*. Even though we often think of this type...

```
(a -> a) -> a -> a
```

... as one of a function of two arguments, we can also read it like...

```
(a -> a) -> (a -> a)
```

... that is, one of a function that takes one argument (an `a -> a` function) and produces a function of one argument (of type `a`). Now if we take...

```
fix :: (b -> b) -> b
```

... we can see how `factabs` fits it by replacing `b` with `(a -> a)`.

> Basically I was trying to figure out how to convert the function `limit` below to something that uses `fix`.

All you need to do is, starting from the original definition, replacing any recursive calls of `limit` with an extra argument and passing this `limit`-with-an-extra-argument to `fix` (as you will see, the types will match with no further ado).

Comment: And in case you are wondering like me, yes `fix factabs` evaluates to `((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) ---->` **`(a -> a)`** indeed

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, here is a version of `limit` function that I posted in my question that uses `fix`:

```
limit :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
limit = fix (\g f x -> let x' = f x
                       in if x == x' then x else g f x')
```